# How does Odium's Intent influence how his magic is obtained?

Tags: cosmere, stormlight-archive

We know that in the Cosmere, the method of obtaining Investiture is tied to the Intent of the Shard it comes from, although the use of the Investiture is not. For instance, Knights Radiant make oaths (Honor) that come from growth as people (Cultivation); Awakeners must be gifted Breath (Endowment); Mistborn need to survive something traumatic (Preservation); Sand Masters become more powerful through something that seems like it could be Autonomous.

How does Odium's form of magic, Voidbinding, tie into his Intent? Presumably it must be obtained through hatred in some sense, but we haven't really seen many Voidbinders. The one human one we know of seems to get it by having a corrupted spren. But perhaps we can conclude something from the Fused or Unmade, or statements made interviews.

Comment: I've seen some speculation (hence the comment) that Odium investiture is a deformation of others, thus the spreen like creatures. It made sense to me.

Comment: Hate does not create but instead it corrupts. Truly in Morgoth's fashion.

Comment: Why does "We know that" in the beginning of question usually be overstatement? This is kinda dubious. What with seeming lack of snapping after Catacendre. Also surgebinding and being knight radiant are two different things.

Comment: @Mithoron - Brandon has explained the general principle of how Intent influences magic in interviews. In the case of  Snapping, Harmony was able to exert some influence and make it milder, but he didn't change its essential nature.

Comment: Well, there may be something of general principle, but it's not particularily prominent. BTW Another thing is we don't know how Renarin's visions work....

Comment: Well, the Heralds got Surgebinding through their Honorblades, yes. But the others are all Knights Radiant.

Comment: I thought about surgebinders before knights - there were no oaths etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89798/discussion-between-mithoron-and-adamant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voidbinding is intentionally not explained much so far in the series: https://wob.coppermind.net/events/332-jordancon-2018/#e9541

However, we do know some things. Renarin is bonded to Glys, a corrupted spren. This corruption comes from Sja-anat, one of the Unmade (I think this is clear enough from *Oathbringer*, but it's also confirmed by Brandon Sanderson here : https://wob.coppermind.net/events/390-stuttgart-signing/#e12705 )

So Renarin is not really using Odium's Investiture anyway, at least not primarily. This is a corrupted, but pre-existing, spren, not a Splinter of Odium as such, and Renarin doesn't look to be using Voidlight, Odium's Investiture "light" (explained more in *Rhythm of War*).

I think that's about as much of an answer as is possible at this point.